# How to Turn 3d dictionary into series of 2d-dataframes with for loop?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, visualization

Good afternoon,
I have a mathematical model to simulate a network of different production facilities. So far I have helped myself for 2d-data visualisation to build individual dataframes for each location.

```
PQ1=pd.DataFrame()
for p_m in VAR1: # sales
    PQ1.loc[p_m,'Volume'] = round(model.calc['P01',p_m](), 2)
    PQ1.loc[p_m,'Quality'] = sum(model.mix3['P01',b_n,p_m]()*mix[b_n][p_m]*q[b_n]['Quality'] for b_n in 
    MIX)/ PQ1.loc[p_m,'Volume']
    ...
PQ2 = pd.DataFrame() 
for p_m in VAR1: # sales
    PQ2.loc[p_m,'Volume'] = round(model.prods['P02',p_m](), 2)...
```

and then plot or export that data for the individual frames. This is nice if you only have 2 or 3 locations. 
I am looking for a smarter way to this, where I can set a for loop like:

```
for l_c in LOCATIONS:
   for p_m in VAR1:
       PQ[l_c].loc[p_m,'Volume'] = round(model.calc[l_c,p_m](),2)
       PQ[l_c].loc[p_m,'Quality'] = sum(model.mix3[l_c,b_n,p_m]()*mix[b_n][p_m]*q[b_n]['Quality']\
       for b_n in MIX)/ PQ[l_c].loc[p_m,'Volume']
```

so that i can subsequently use for loops to visualise/export the data. 
Building the 3d dataframe is straightforward, however after creation I struggle to convert it back to the desired 3 dimensional dataframe. which i could adress the data as PQ[l_c,p_m,'Volume'] and create the desired 2d location specific dataframes.

Thanks in advance for any help.
regards
p.

---

a bit more information on what the output currently looks like:
[example output dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wX5pl.png). at the moment each of them is generated manually. taking data from a pyomo calculation. however i want to be more flexible adding a higher resolution to the model, hence having more locations or nodes as the experts call it. so if i could generate those two dimensional tables with a for loop slicing and dicing the multidimensional pyomo data, that would be extremely helpful for visualisation.
if i had to frame it a bit more scientific: i have the result of a pyomo model that produces an optimised output that consists of many 1000 discrete values and I would like to loop over some of them to produce series of 2 dimensional outputs x, f(x) that i can then visualise with barcharts or line-graphs in matplotlib. as show n in the example i currently manually have to fix 'P01' and  then can only show values for different products p_m with a defined 'Quality'. When i try to loop over multiple 'P0i's' it produces an error message:

```
KeyError: "None of [Index(['P01', 'Product1', 'Volume'], dtype='object')] are in the [index]"
```

Comment: Can U provide an example DataFrame with ur expected outputs? Easier to understand your question with examples of what u have and what u want ur final output to look like

Comment: I think i have solved it. I now write first everything to a dictionary which has keys `[P0_i, Product_j, 'Quality_k']` with a value against it. Then i run a for loop across all production facilities, and within the loop i create the 2 dimensional dataframes taking data out of the dictionary for the particular facility and this is then written to multiple excel sheets or can be used for visualisation.